# What is a FolderRelativeId for a storage item?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

It is written in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.istorageitemproperties.folderrelativeid):

> An identifier for the current item. This ID is unique for the query
>   result or StorageFolder that contains the item and can be used to
>   distinguish between items that have the same name.

But it still isn't clear to me. Can I use it as a unique id which helps me to compare equality of any two given files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great article about [FolderRelativeId](http://codepb.com/finding-if-storagefile-is-in-storagefolder/).  It basically is an unique ID for a file.

There is a **difference** between a file with the **same name** and a file that is an **exact copy** of the another file (which should have the same FolderRelativeId).

---

A good use for such an ID is when you're updating a huge program.  Why copy files from the new update if there is one already on disk that is exactly the same, just skip that file and go to the next.

Comment: I want if we listed all files which are stored on the phone, non of them have the same id.